# Apps that send Push Notifications without first obtaining user consent will be rejected?

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

I read this on appstore guidelines and was wondering what it means?

The device already asks if the user wants to receive push notifications, Right?
The user can also turn off push notifications if necessary.
My app does use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];` when the user selects not to receive push notifications.

What else needs to be done if i have to follow apples' guidelines on this?

I also have the same kind of question on

**Apps that do not notify and obtain user consent before collecting, transmitting, or using
location data will be rejected**

Same as push notifications, location based services also work only when the user approves it right?

Can somebody shed some light on this!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Location will prompt the user for permission before sending data. As soon as you try to spool up a CLLocationManager, it'll check if the app has permission, and it'll check on a time-based basis after that. As long as you're not using a lower-level call to try and get the user's location, you'll be fine.

Re: push notifications, just make sure you're using the feedback service to detect when people uninstall your apps, and you'll be okay

**EDIT:**
For more information on the feedback service, check out "The Feedback Service" at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html

Basically, you check the feedback service every so often, and ensure that the user's device token isn't on the list. If it is, check that they haven't reregistered for push notifications, and it that's the case, then you remove them from your sending list

Comment: THanks jeremy, that's helpful. But since you mentioned it, i did'nt think of that, can you point me to some resource on how to disable apns when the user uninstalls the app?

Comment: I've modified the answer to include that info. If you can, look for a library that does the heavy lifting for you. I've heard good things about apns-sharp if you don't want to write your own feedback client.